# Custom init from from NSClassFromString

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

I try to dynamically call certain viewController/Feature depends on his Name.`NSClassFromString`
(that kind of idea was suggested by Facebook).
For Instance from my  server I can define in IOS app which feature or viewController should be used.(or On/Off them)
 
I searched all over Stack but still cant find an elegant way to implement what I want

```
   Class myclass = NSClassFromString(className);
   id obj = [[myclass alloc] init];
```

will work.
But I would like to call my custom init.

```
Class myclass = NSClassFromString(className);
id obj = [[myclass alloc] initWithCostumInitializer:userInfo];
```

I cant find a proper way to do it. Of course every time I receive an error because `initWithCostumInitializer` is not recognised.So I need to make the decision in run time.I believe I missing something.

Tnx a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't get a *compile-time* error about an unknown method if the headers for the possible classe(s) are imported into the .m file where this code is running. Because of exactly this sort of dynamism, ObjC should let you get away with calling fairly arbitrary methods on objects of type `id`.

But that's just a bandaid solution. Really, if you know that that custom initializer method is present, then it's not an arbitrary class, right? You have some idea what kind of object it is, or at least what kind of base class it derives from, otherwise you wouldn't know to call that method. So you could always:

```
id customObj = [((BaseViewController *)[myclass alloc]) initWithCustumInitializer:userInfo];
```

---

If your error is a *runtime* error about the receiver missing that selector, then you have a real problem, which is: why are you calling a named method on an object that might not be the kind of object that has that method? If that's what's happening, you'll need to look at the class *first* to figure out what kind of thing you're actually about to create, and then behave appropriately for the init.

Comment: Tnx Ben you r totally correct I should simply import the .h.....(I should thought about it) In my case I don't know which class should be called so I am not sure if the second solution can help me.